# In Kotlin, why the load method from Neo4j OGM returns null if the @Id property is named "id"?

Tags: kotlin, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Using the sample below (based on [this source](https://gist.github.com/michael-simons/1433ad4969023d1a32b359f908f6ce2f#file-application-kt) but with some changes), if the property `@Id` is named "id", the Neo4J (latest version) does not recognizes the attribute when the `load` is executed. But if I named it to any other name, such as "myId", the method works. Please, does anyone know why?

My code:

```kotlin
package sample

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory

@NodeEntity
data class Actor(
  @Id
  var id: Long?,
  var name:String
)  {
  constructor() : this(-1, "")
  @Relationship(type = "ACTS_IN", direction = "OUTGOING")
  var movies = mutableSetOf<Movie>()

  fun actsIn(movie: Movie) {
    movies.add(movie)
    movie.actors.add(this)
  }
}

@NodeEntity
data class Movie(
  @Id
  var id: Long?,
  var title:String,
  var released:Int
)  {
  constructor() : this(-1L, "", -1)

  @Relationship(type = "ACTS_IN", direction = "INCOMING")
  var actors = mutableSetOf<Actor>()
}

class Sample {
  private val uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
  val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
    .uri(uri)
    //.credentials("neo4j", "test")
    .build()

  val sessionFactory = SessionFactory(configuration, "sample")

  fun save() {
    val pack = SessionFactory::class.java.name
    val l = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(pack)
    l.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.ALL)

    val session = sessionFactory.openSession()

    val develsAdvocate = Movie(1, "The Devil’s Advocate", 1997)
    val theMatrix = Movie(2, "The Matrix", 1999)

    val act = Actor(1, "Carrie-Anne Moss")
    act.actsIn(theMatrix)

    val keanu = Actor(2, "Keanu Reeves")
    keanu.actsIn(theMatrix)
    keanu.actsIn(develsAdvocate)

    session.save(develsAdvocate)
    session.save(theMatrix)

    session.clear()

    // ** Only works if the entity has a attribute @Id with name different as "id"
    val theMatrixReloaded = session.load(Movie::class.java, theMatrix.id, 2)

    println("Found ${theMatrixReloaded.title}")
    for (actor in theMatrixReloaded.actors) {
      println("Actor ${actor.name} acted in ${actor.movies.joinToString { it.title }}")
    }

    sessionFactory.close()
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val neoInstance = Sample()

  neoInstance.save()
}
```

Comment: From [the Neo4J Docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:entity-identifier):  `If the field of type Long is simply named 'id' then it is not necessary to annotate it with @Id @GeneratedValue as Neo4j-OGM will use it automatically as native id.`

Comment: @gabriel-pizarro, have you tested the code with this suggestion? It doesn't work, the 'load' method returns null. Note in my code that I need to inform the entity id value, I don't want Neo4J to generate a value for it. So, I understand that you need to at least set '@Id' in the class attribute.

Comment: I have not tested it; I was hoping to point out something you may have missed. According to the docs, any field `id: Long?` will automatically be used as if it has the annotations Id and GeneratedValue. I don't know if there is a way to disable this behavior, so you may need to just rename your variable as a workaround. Since this isn't optimal, I didn't write it as an answer, just a comment.

Comment: @GabrielPizarro, absolutely, I really appreciate your comment. I've tried it in various ways and, for me, the method doesn't work if I don't rename the attribute. Let's wait if  anyone has a solution. Thank you very much!